# How to toggle a separate drop down beneath a grid of items using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Honestly, I'm at the end of my rope here because I am a total newbie at jquery and the like. My wording might be confusing, so let me explain. Picture a screen with multiple icons, and under these icons is a button. When clicked on, this button makes another box under this icon, of a different size, appear underneath. I've figured out how to make things toggle on click, more or less ... however the problem I'm having is that when I use this same button on the icon following it, it opens both the box under icon number one and the box from icon number two ... because the boxes are appearing in the same place, icon number two's box does not appear where i want it-right under icon number two. does that make sense ? What I want is for the box to appear in the same place relative to the icon - right under it. And I want to be able to add in as many icons ( and thus dropdown boxes ) as I'd like. Here is my code:

## JQUERY

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/isotope-layout@3.0/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

$(".name").click(function () {
    $(".drop").toggle("slow");
});

    $('.grid').isotope({
  // options...
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  masonry: {
columnWidth: 100
  }
});

});
</script>
```

## CSS

```
.grid {
margin: auto;
margin-bottom: 50px;
max-width: 600px;
height: 100%;
}

.grid:after {
display: block;
clear: both;
content: '';
}

.grid-item {
position: relative;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 10px;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}

.grid-item img {
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}

.icon {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.name {
background-color: #000;
color:#fff;
font-size: 8px;
font-family: 'silkscreen';
position: relative;
margin-top: 115px;
padding:3px;
margin-left: 40px;
border: none;
text-align: left;
width: 150px;
}

.name:focus {
outline: 0;
}

.drop {
height: 300px;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
top: 150px;
font-size: 10px;
display: none;
}
```

## HTML

```
<body>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="icon"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/aN7vtIU.png"></div>
    <button class="name">NAME</button>
<div class="drop">DROPDOWN TEXT</div>
  </div>


  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="icon">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aN7vtIU.png">
    </div>
    <button class="name">NAME</button>
<div class="drop">DROPDOWN TEXT</div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Many thanks in advance! I've been trying to crack this one all day to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're selector is too broad. What you've told jQuery is to find all elements with a `.name` class and when **any** are clicked, find all elements with a `.drop` class and toggle them.

To apply the toggle to the `.drop` that's relative to the clicked `.name` element you need to do some DOM traversal. This traversal includes:

- travel up the hierarchy to the nearest `.grid-item` parent
- find the next adjacent `.drop` element after said `.grid-item`
- apply the `.toggle()` only to that

**ORIGINAL:** By traversing this way, we can be more specific and only select the exact element we want to toggle.

```
$('.name').click(function () {
    $(this) // wrap this, it always refers to the clicked event element
        .parents('.grid-item') // find parent grid item
        .next('.drop') // find adjacent drop
        .toggle('slow'); // only toggle that one element
});
```

**EDIT:** Code update to handle the `.drop` now being **inside** the `.grid-element` (see comments for more details).

```
$('.name').click(function () {
    $(this) // wrap this, it always refers to the clicked event element
        .parents('.grid-item') // find parent grid item
        .find('.drop') // find drop descendant
        .toggle('slow'); // only toggle that one element
});
```

Remember, changing the HTML structure means that very specific DOM traversals will need to be updated accordingly.

<strike>**As a side note**, your HTML structure is awfully fragile. I'd recommend putting putting your `.drop` inside the `.grid-item` itself. This way the entire thing is one self-contained unit. If you need the drop to hang below the item that can be easily achieved using CSS and absolutely positioning the `.drop` to `top: 100%`.</strike>

Comment: Awesome! thank you. The sole problem I have now is that the button does nothing on click. The text is there, and the box is appearing where it should relative to the icon...but this is without display:none; under .drop {. once I add it, clicking on the name button does not toggle it.

Also thanks for the side note! I've changed the html I'm working with now accordingly.

Comment: Make sure that the drop element isn't covering your button. You should see the button highlight when you hover over it. Additionally, you can use the inspector in Chrome or Firefox to highlight elements to see where they're positioned.

Comment: That's because the jquery I sent you won't work anymore; it's looking for the `.drop` BESIDE the `.grid-item`, you've now got it INSIDE the `.grid-item`. You need to use `.find()` to locate children/descendants. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: that worked perfectly! many thanks for your help and patience.